# String that contains $1

Tags: python, string, subprocess

I have a script that scrolls through all the folders of unzipped files and get information of the contents.

The problem is in the name of files such as:

```
filename="SearchView$10.smali"
```

Because if I want to get the stats the $1 in the string disappears,and I get the following error:

```
    subprocess.check_output("stat "+ filename,shell=True)
cannot open `SearchView0.smali' (No such file or directory)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid `shell=True`, [it leads to security issues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations). And it is also at the root of your problem, as the `$1` is interpreted.

Do this instead:

```
subprocess.check_output(["stat", filename])
```